# Why am I getting 'Direct IP access not allowed` with NGINX and SSL using localhost?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I know there are a bunch of these questions but I can't find any that answer my question so here is another one. I am trying to create a simple NGINX proxy that just proxies my existing site to localhost. The existing site is jackiergleason.com. I set up my NGINX like this...

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name localhost;
 ssl_certificate     /usr/src/app/host.cert;
 ssl_certificate_key /usr/src/app/host.key;
 location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_ssl_name $host;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_pass https://jackiergleason.com;
 }
}
```

I use docker to run it locally like this..

```
FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pwd
COPY host.cert /usr/src/app
COPY host.key /usr/src/app
RUN ls -al /usr/src/app
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Then I run these 2 commands...

```
docker build . -t jrg/proxy:latest
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:443 --name web jrg/proxy:latest
```

But when I try to access `https://localhost:8080` and accept the security warning I get...

[image]

What am I missing?

I also tried using port 443 but I get the same result

Comment: The problem is that you're making a request to a host named `localhost`, and you';re passing this hostname on to the remote server, which doesn't know what to do with it. What you have written is effectively `curl -H "Host: localhost" https://jackiergleason.com`

Comment: You can probably get things working by replacing `$host` with `jackiergleason.com` in your nginx config.

Comment: Looks like that worked @larsks I will accept that as the answer

Comment: Might be nice to have a little explanation as to how localhost is considered a direct IP and why the regular host can't be used like the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_ssl_name $host;
```

With

```
proxy_set_header Host jackiergleason.com;
proxy_ssl_name jackiergleason.com;
```

Worked